# Как работает подписка Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Пожалуйста, разъясните один момент: Если пользователь оформил подписку на платный контент а приложении, как программа проводит проверку того, что эта подписка до сих пор действительна, например, без интернета? Или приложение ориентируется по дате на устройстве (Что очень маловероятно). Или люди вообще не имеют доступа к платному контенту по подписке без интернета?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информация о наличии у юзера подписки получается путём запроса к `playMarket`. У него внутри какая-то там магия с кэшем и даже без интернета маркет будет отвечать что у юзера есть активная подписка. Сам в доках не находил инфы, но, думаю, этот кэш обновляется с достаточной переодичностью для того, чтобы и без интернета максимально неустаревшие данные выдавать и чтобы препятствовать покупке подписки, отмены оной, и пользованию приложением, думающим, что юзер всё ещё подписан.

Лично я просто доверяю тому что отвечает маркет на мои запросы по поводу наличия чего-то купленного и не вдаюсь в детали актуализации этой информации маркетом